# How javascript code coverage tools work internally?

Tags: javascript, code-coverage

I have understood for java code coverage tools like jacoco. but i see that there are a lot of javascript code coverage tools available. I am just getting curious, that how do they work internally and give us the percentage report.

Comment: I wanna know too; Just an answer that even barely hits home would be ideal if this doens't get closed down.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, these tools add extra code to our inspected files to count function and line *hits*. These tools store this *hits* in a map, where you could find the file and functions related to each line.

After that is pretty easy to calculate the coverage of each file/function.

I just found this information [here](https://gist.github.com/robertknight/834452c3b06963ff2a8b9682fd4189cb), Istanbul is an example of code coverage tooling in JS. There's a lot more!